# Multi-threaded HD Image classifier using a neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, machine-learning, neural-network

**This is a follow up to the code found here:**

[Multithreaded HD Image Processing + Logistic reg. Classifier + Visualization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235581/multithreaded-hd-image-processing-logistic-reg-classifier-visualization)

**Description:**

This code takes a label and a folder path of subfolders as input that have certain labels ex: trees, cats with each folder containing a list of HD photos corresponding to the folder name, then a multithreaded image processor converts data to .h5 format and classifies photos with the given label using logistic regression or a neural network.

The following link has the code below as well as the necessary .h5 files to make it work and demonstrate an example on classifying dog photos but feel free to test with your own image data and i'm awaiting your feedback for optimizations/improvements/reducing runtime...

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=19FqVNsbm72dDP6WTDDXqIXv5ZoZbpHbr

**Updates:**

- Added a neural network implementation based on Andrew NG's Deep learning course
- Wrapped everything into a class `ImageClassifier`
- Added some logging and more error checks.
- Better organization of the code.
- Added more training examples

Running the code with `random_seed=151` should give the following results:

- **Initial sample:**

[image: initial]

- **Sample of the results with 72% accuracy on the test set:**

[image: res]

- **Learning curve(neural net) `max_iter=7000, learning_rate=0.015`:**

[image: lc]

**Code:**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import perf_counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import shutil
import cv2
import os


class ImageClassifier:
    """
    A tool for classifying and labeling HD images.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        folder_path,
        target_label,
        new_image_size=(80, 80),
        threads=5,
        fig_size=(9, 9),
        random_seed=None,
        save_figs=False,
        norm_value=255,
        sample_dimensions=(2, 5),
        display_progress=True,
        log_file=None,
        layer_dimensions=(20, 7, 5, 1),
        initial_parameter_mode='he',
        learning_rate=0.0005,
        max_iter=2000,
        display_nth_iteration=100,
        test_size=0.2,
        display_figs=None,
        new_hdf=False,
        show_figs=True,
    ):
        """
        Initialize classification of a given folder.
        Args:
            folder_path: Path to folder containing labeled sub-folders of images.
            target_label: One of the sub-folders name (label to classify).
            new_image_size: Image resizing new dimensions.
            threads: Number of image processing threads.
            fig_size: Display figure dimensions.
            random_seed: int representing a random seed.
            save_figs: If True, all figures specified will be saved.
            norm_value: Normalization value, in this case, 255 the maximum value of a pixel channel.
            sample_dimensions: (n_rows, n_columns) dimensions of sample display subplots.
            display_progress: If False, progress and results of the classification will not be displayed.
            log_file: Path to .txt file name to log the classification progress and results
            layer_dimensions: Neural network hidden layer dimensions.
            initial_parameter_mode: Initial model parameter initialization mode:
                'sq': Square root
                'z': Zeros
            learning_rate: The learning rate of the classifier.
            max_iter: Maximum number of iterations for the optimization algorithm(gradient descent)
            display_nth_iteration: Display current cost every n iterations.
                'lr': logistic regression.
                'nn': Neural network.
            test_size: Percentage of the test set size.
            display_figs: A list of figures to plot.
                'i': If in list, initial sample will be displayed.
                'lc': If in list, the learning curve will be displayed.
                'r': If in list, the results correct sample will be displayed.
                'e': If in list, the results false sample will be displayed.
            new_hdf: If True, New .hdf file will be created for every sub-folder.
            show_figs: If False, plotted figures will not be displayed.
        """
        assert os.path.isdir(folder_path)
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        if target_label not in os.listdir(folder_path):
            raise ValueError(
                f'Invalid label: {target_label} Folder not found in {folder_path}'
            )
        self.target_label = target_label
        self.new_image_size = new_image_size
        self.threads = threads
        self.fig_size = fig_size
        if random_seed:
            np.random.seed(random_seed)
        self.random_seed = random_seed
        self.save_figs = save_figs
        self.norm_value = norm_value
        self.sample_dimensions = sample_dimensions
        self.display_progress = display_progress
        self.log_file = log_file
        self.layer_dimensions = layer_dimensions
        self.initial_parameter_mode = initial_parameter_mode
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.display_nth_iteration = display_nth_iteration
        assert isinstance(display_nth_iteration, int)
        self.test_size = test_size
        assert 0 <= test_size <= 1
        self.display_figs = display_figs
        self.new_hdf = new_hdf
        self.flat_dimensions = []
        self.show_figs = show_figs

    def display_message(self, message):
        """
        Print a message to the console and log to a .txt file.
        Args:
            message: Message to be printed.

        Return:
            None
        """
        if self.display_progress:
            print(message)
        if self.log_file:
            print(message, end='\n', file=open(self.log_file, 'a'))

    def read_and_resize(self, image):
        """
        Read and resize image.
        Args:
            image: Image path.

        Return:
             Resized Image.
        """
        try:
            image = cv2.imread(image)
            return cv2.resize(image, self.new_image_size)
        except cv2.error:
            pass

    def folder_to_hdf(self, folder_path):
        """
        Save a folder images to hdf format.
        Args:
            folder_path: Path to folder containing images.

        Return:
             None
        """
        label = folder_path.split('/')[-2]
        data, resized = pd.DataFrame(), []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.threads) as executor:
            future_resized_images = {
                executor.submit(self.read_and_resize, folder_path + img): img
                for img in os.listdir(folder_path)
                if img and img != '.DS_Store'
            }
            for future in as_completed(future_resized_images):
                result = future.result()
                resized.append(result)
                self.display_message(
                    f'Processing ({label})-{future_resized_images[future]} ... done.'
                )
                del future_resized_images[future]
            data['Images'] = resized
            data['Label'] = label
            data.to_hdf(folder_path + label + '.h5', label)

    def folders_to_hdf(self, sub_folders=None):
        """
        Convert image data(for every sub-folder self.folder_path) to .hdf format.
        Args:
            sub_folders: A list of sub_folder names to convert.

        Return:
            None
        """
        if not sub_folders:
            for folder_name in os.listdir(self.folder_path):
                if folder_name != '.DS_Store':
                    path = ''.join([self.folder_path, folder_name, '/'])
                    self.folder_to_hdf(path)
        if sub_folders:
            for folder_name in sub_folders:
                path = ''.join([self.folder_path, folder_name, '/'])
                if folder_name not in os.listdir(self.folder_path):
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f'Folder {path}')
                self.folder_to_hdf(path)

    def clear_hdf(self, sub_folders=None):
        """
        Delete every .h5 for every sub-folder in  self.folder_path.
        Args:
            sub_folders: A list of sub_folder names to clear from .hdf files.

        Return:
            None
        """
        if not sub_folders:
            for folder_name in os.listdir(self.folder_path):
                if folder_name != '.DS_Store':
                    try:
                        file_name = ''.join(
                            [self.folder_path, folder_name, '/', folder_name, '.h5']
                        )
                        os.remove(file_name)
                        self.display_message(f'Removed {file_name.split("/")[-1]}')
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        pass
        if sub_folders:
            for folder_name in sub_folders:
                file_name = ''.join(
                    [self.folder_path, folder_name, '/', folder_name, '.h5']
                )
                if folder_name not in os.listdir(self.folder_path):
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f'File not found {file_name}')
                try:
                    os.remove(file_name)
                    self.display_message(f'Removed {file_name.split("/")[-1]}')
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass

    def load_hdf(self, sub_folders=None):
        """
        Load classification data from .h5 files.
        Args:
            sub_folders: Sub-folders to load.

        Return:
             (x, y, frames).
        """
        file_names = []
        if not sub_folders:
            file_names = [
                ''.join([self.folder_path, folder_name, '/', folder_name, '.h5'])
                for folder_name in os.listdir(self.folder_path)
                if folder_name != '.DS_Store'
            ]
        if sub_folders:
            for folder_name in sub_folders:
                path = ''.join([self.folder_path, folder_name, '/', folder_name, '.h5'])
                if folder_name not in os.listdir(self.folder_path):
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f'File not found {path}')
            file_names = [
                ''.join([self.folder_path, folder_name, '/', folder_name, '.h5'])
                for folder_name in sub_folders
            ]
        frames = [pd.read_hdf(file_name) for file_name in file_names]
        frames = pd.concat(frames).dropna()
        frames['Classification'] = 0
        frames.loc[frames['Label'] == self.target_label, 'Classification'] = 1
        new_index = np.random.permutation(frames.index)
        frames.index = new_index
        frames.sort_index(inplace=True)
        image_data, labels = (
            np.array(list(frames['Images'])),
            np.array(list(frames['Classification'])),
        )
        return image_data, labels, frames

    def display_sample_images(self, title, image_data, labels=None):
        """
        Plot and display a sample of size(self.sample_dimensions).
        Args:
            title: Title of the sample image.
            image_data: numpy array of image data.
            labels: numpy array of label data(0s and 1s).

        Return:
            None
        """
        if not self.show_figs and not self.save_figs:
            return
        rows, columns = self.sample_dimensions
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=self.fig_size)
        plt.title(title)
        for i in range(rows * columns):
            img = image_data[i]
            ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i + 1)
            if isinstance(labels, np.ndarray):
                ax.title.set_text(f'Prediction: {labels[i]}')
            plt.imshow(img)
        if self.save_figs:
            plt.savefig(title + '.png')
        if self.show_figs:
            plt.show()

    def pre_process(self, sub_folders=None):
        """
        Split the data into train and test sets and prepare the data for further processing.
        Args:
            sub_folders: Sub-folders to load.

        Return:
            x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, frames.
        """
        image_data, labels, frames = self.load_hdf(sub_folders)
        rows, columns = self.sample_dimensions
        total_images = len(image_data)
        title = (
            f'Initial(before prediction) {rows} x {columns} '
            f'data sample (Classification of {self.target_label})'
        )
        if self.display_figs and 'i' in self.display_figs:
            self.display_sample_images(title, image_data)
        image_data = image_data.reshape(total_images, -1) / self.norm_value
        labels = labels.reshape(total_images, -1)
        separation_index = int(self.test_size * total_images)
        x_train = image_data[separation_index:].T
        y_train = labels[separation_index:].T
        x_test = image_data[:separation_index].T
        y_test = labels[:separation_index].T
        self.flat_dimensions.append(x_train.shape[0])
        self.display_message(f'Total number of images: {total_images}')
        self.display_message(f'x_train shape: {x_train.shape}')
        self.display_message(f'y_train shape: {y_train.shape}')
        self.display_message(f'x_test shape: {x_test.shape}')
        self.display_message(f'y_test shape: {y_test.shape}')
        return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, frames

    def initialize_parameters(self):
        """
        Initialize weights and bias for the given layer of the neural network dimensions.
        Return:
            A dictionary containing parameters [w1, w2, ... wn] and [b1, b2, ... bn].
        """
        parameters = {}
        self.flat_dimensions.extend(self.layer_dimensions)
        layer_dimensions = self.flat_dimensions
        for n in range(1, len(layer_dimensions)):
            if self.initial_parameter_mode == 'he':
                parameters['w' + str(n)] = np.random.randn(
                    layer_dimensions[n], layer_dimensions[n - 1]
                ) * (np.sqrt(2.0 / layer_dimensions[n - 1]))
                parameters['b' + str(n)] = np.zeros((layer_dimensions[n], 1))
            if self.initial_parameter_mode == 'sq':
                parameters['w' + str(n)] = np.random.randn(
                    layer_dimensions[n], layer_dimensions[n - 1]
                ) / np.sqrt(layer_dimensions[n - 1])
                parameters['b' + str(n)] = np.zeros((layer_dimensions[n], 1))
            if self.initial_parameter_mode == 'z':
                parameters['w' + str(n)] = np.zeros(
                    (layer_dimensions[n], layer_dimensions[n - 1])
                )
                parameters['b' + str(n)] = np.zeros((layer_dimensions[n], 1))
        return parameters

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(x):
        """
        Calculate sigmoid function(logistic regression).
        Args:
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images).

        Return:
            sigmoid(x).
        """
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid_nn(x):
        """
        Apply the sigmoid function(neural network).
        Args:
            x: numpy array of inputs.

        Return:
            a, x
            a: Output of sigmoid.
        """
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), x

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid_back(da, z):
        """
        Back propagate a single Sigmoid unit(neural network).
        Args:
            da: Post activation gradient.
            z: The output of the linear layer.

        Return:
            dz: gradient of the cost with respect to z.
        """
        sig = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
        dz = da * sig * (1 - sig)
        return dz

    @staticmethod
    def relu(z):
        """
        Apply the RELU function(neural network).
        Args:
            z: The output of the linear layer.

        Return:
            a, z
            a: Output of RELU.
        """
        return np.maximum(0, z), z

    @staticmethod
    def relu_back(da, z):
        """
        Back propagate a single RELU unit(neural network).
        Args:
            da: Post activation gradient.
            z: The output of the linear layer.

        Return:
            dz: gradient of the cost with respect to z.
        """
        dz = np.array(da, copy=True)
        dz[z <= 0] = 0
        return dz

    def compute_cost(self, w, b, x, y):
        """
        Compute cost function using forward and back propagation(logistic regression).
        Args:
            w: numpy array of weights(also called Theta).
            b: Bias(int)
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images)
            y: Label numpy array of labels(0s and 1s)

        Return:
            Cost and gradient(dw and db).
        """
        total_images = x.shape[1]
        activation = self.sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, x) + b)
        cost = (-1 / total_images) * (
            np.sum(y * np.log(activation) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - activation))
        )
        cost = np.squeeze(cost)
        dw = (1 / total_images) * np.dot(x, (activation - y).T)
        db = (1 / total_images) * np.sum(activation - y)
        return cost, dw, db

    @staticmethod
    def compute_cost_nn(last_activation, y):
        """
        Compute the cost function for the neural network using forward propagation.
        Args:
            last_activation: The last post-activation value.
            y: numpy array of labels.

        Return:
            Cross-entropy cost.
        """
        cost = -(
            y * np.log(last_activation) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - last_activation)
        ).mean()
        return np.squeeze(cost)

    @staticmethod
    def linear_forward(a, w, b):
        """
        Apply the linear part of a single layer's forward propagation.
        Args:
            a: Activations from previous layer(or inputs X)
            w: numpy array of weights.
            b: numpy array of bias.

        Return:
            z, a, w, b
            z: The pre-activation parameter.
        """
        z = np.dot(w, a) + b
        return z, a, w, b

    def linear_activation_forward(self, a_prev, a_func, w, b):
        """
        Apply the forward propagation for the LINEAR->ACTIVATION layer.
        Args:
            a_prev: Activations from previous layer(or inputs X)
            a_func: Activation function 's' for sigmoid or 'r' for RELU.
            w: numpy array of weights.
            b: numpy array of bias.

        Return:
            post_a, linear_cache, activation_cache.
        """
        linear_cache, activation_cache, post_a = 0, 0, 0
        if a_func == 's':
            z, *linear_cache = self.linear_forward(a_prev, w, b)
            post_a, activation_cache = self.sigmoid_nn(z)
        if a_func == 'r':
            z, *linear_cache = self.linear_forward(a_prev, w, b)
            post_a, activation_cache = self.relu(z)
        return post_a, linear_cache, activation_cache

    def forward_prop(self, x, parameters):
        """
        Apply forward propagation for the [LINEAR- > RELU] * (L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID computation
        Args:
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images).
            parameters: A dictionary of initial parameters.

        Return: last_activation, caches.
            last_activation: The last post-activation value.
            caches: A list of caches containing every cache of linear_activation_forward()
        """
        caches = []
        activation = x
        layers = len(parameters) // 2
        for layer in range(1, layers):
            a_prev = activation
            current_weights = parameters['w' + str(layer)]
            current_bias = parameters['b' + str(layer)]
            activation, *cache = self.linear_activation_forward(
                a_prev, 'r', current_weights, current_bias
            )
            caches.append(cache)
        last_weight = parameters['w' + str(layers)]
        last_bias = parameters['b' + str(layers)]
        last_activation, *cache = self.linear_activation_forward(
            activation, 's', last_weight, last_bias
        )
        caches.append(cache)
        return last_activation, caches

    @staticmethod
    def linear_back(dz, cache):
        """
        Apply the linear part of a single neural network layer's back propagation.
        Args:
            dz: Gradient of the cost with respect to the linear output of current layer.
            cache: A tuple containing current layer's forward propagation cache(a_prev, w, b).

        Return:
            da_prev, dw, db
                da_prev: Gradient of the cost with respect to the activation(of previous layer)
                dw: Gradient of the cost with respect to w
                db: Gradient of the cost with respect to b
        """
        a_prev, w, b = cache
        m = a_prev.shape[1]
        dw = np.dot(dz, a_prev.T) / m
        db = np.sum(dz, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
        da_prev = np.dot(w.T, dz)
        return da_prev, dw, db

    def linear_activation_back(self, a_func, da, cache):
        """
        Apply the back propagation for the LINEAR->ACTIVATION layer.
        Args:
            a_func: Activation function 's' for sigmoid or 'r' for RELU.
            da: Post activation gradient for current layer.
            cache: linear_cache, activation_cache from linear_activation_forward().

        Return:
            da_prev, dw, db
                da_prev: Gradient of the cost with respect to the activation(of previous layer)
                dw: Gradient of the cost with respect to w
                db: Gradient of the cost with respect to b
        """
        da_prev, dw, db = 0, 0, 0
        linear_cache, activation_cache = cache
        if a_func == 's':
            dz = self.sigmoid_back(da, activation_cache)
            da_prev, dw, db = self.linear_back(dz, linear_cache)
        if a_func == 'r':
            dz = self.relu_back(da, activation_cache)
            da_prev, dw, db = self.linear_back(dz, linear_cache)
        return da_prev, dw, db

    def back_prop(self, last_activation, y, caches):
        """
        Apply the backward propagation for the [LINEAR->RELU] * (L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID group.
        Args:
            last_activation: The last post-activation value.
            y: numpy array of labels.
            caches: A list of caches containing every cache of linear_activation_forward()

        Return:
            A dictionary of gradients.
        """
        grads = {}
        layers = len(caches)
        y = y.reshape(last_activation.shape)
        d_last_activation = -(
            np.divide(y, last_activation) - np.divide(1 - y, 1 - last_activation)
        )
        current_cache = caches[layers - 1]
        (
            grads['da' + str(layers)],
            grads['dw' + str(layers)],
            grads['db' + str(layers)],
        ) = self.linear_activation_back('s', d_last_activation, current_cache)
        for layer in reversed(range(layers - 1)):
            current_cache = caches[layer]
            da_prev_temp, dw_temp, db_temp = self.linear_activation_back(
                'r', grads['da' + str(layer + 2)], current_cache
            )
            grads['da' + str(layer + 1)] = da_prev_temp
            grads['dw' + str(layer + 1)] = dw_temp
            grads['db' + str(layer + 1)] = db_temp
        return grads

    @staticmethod
    def update_params(parameters, grads, learning_rate):
        """
        Update parameters for gradient descent(neural network).
        Args:
            parameters: A dictionary of initial parameters.
            grads: A dictionary of gradients.
            learning_rate: The learning rate of gradient descent.

        Return:
            Updated parameters.
        """
        layers = len(parameters) // 2
        for layer in range(layers):
            weight_decrease = learning_rate * grads['dw' + str(layer + 1)]
            parameters['w' + str(layer + 1)] -= weight_decrease
            bias_decrease = learning_rate * grads['db' + str(layer + 1)]
            parameters['b' + str(layer + 1)] -= bias_decrease
        return parameters

    def g_descent(self, w, b, x, y):
        """
        Optimize weights and bias using gradient descent algorithm(logistic regression).
        Args:
            w: numpy array of weights(also called Theta).
            b: Bias(int)
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images)
            y: Label numpy array of labels(0s and 1s)

        Return:
            w, b, dw, db, costs
        """
        dw, db, costs = 0, 0, []
        for iteration in range(self.max_iter):
            cost, dw, db = self.compute_cost(w, b, x, y)
            w -= dw * self.learning_rate
            b -= db * self.learning_rate
            costs.append(cost)
            if iteration % self.display_nth_iteration == 0:
                self.display_message(
                    f'Iteration number: {iteration} out of {self.max_iter} iterations'
                )
                self.display_message(f'Current cost: {cost}\n')
        return w, b, dw, db, costs

    def g_descent_nn(self, x, y, parameters):
        """
        Optimize weights and bias using gradient descent algorithm(neural network).
        Args:
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images)
            y: Label numpy array of labels(0s and 1s)
            parameters: A dictionary of initial parameters(weights/bias).

        Return:
            parameters, costs
        """
        costs = []
        for iteration in range(self.max_iter):
            last_activation, caches = self.forward_prop(x, parameters)
            current_cost = self.compute_cost_nn(last_activation, y)
            costs.append(current_cost)
            grads = self.back_prop(last_activation, y, caches)
            parameters = self.update_params(parameters, grads, self.learning_rate)
            if iteration % self.display_nth_iteration == 0:
                self.display_message(
                    f'Iteration number: {iteration} out of {self.max_iter} iterations'
                )
                self.display_message(f'Current cost: {current_cost}\n')
        return parameters, costs

    def predict(self, w, b, x):
        """
        Predict labels of x (logistic regression).
        Args:
            w: numpy array of weights(also called Theta).
            b: Bias(int)
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images)

        Return:
            Y^ numpy array of predictions.
        """
        w = w.reshape(x.shape[0], 1)
        activation = self.sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, x) + b)
        activation[activation > 0.5] = 1
        activation[activation <= 0.5] = 0
        return activation

    def predict_nn(self, x, parameters):
        """
        Predict labels using a neural network.
        Args:
            x: Image data in the following shape(pixels * pixels * 3, number of images)
            parameters: A dictionary of parameters of the trained model.

        Return:
            Y^ numpy array of predictions.
        """
        last_activation, caches = self.forward_prop(x, parameters)
        last_activation[last_activation > 0.5] = 1
        last_activation[last_activation <= 0.5] = 0
        return last_activation

    def plot_figure(self, figure_type, frames=None, costs=None):
        """
        Plot samples or learning curve.
        Args:
            figure_type: String indication of the figure to plot.
            frames: pandas DataFrame with the image data.
            costs: A list of costs for plotting the learning curve.
        Return:
            None
        """
        rows, columns = self.sample_dimensions[0], self.sample_dimensions[1]
        sample_size = rows * columns
        if figure_type == 'lc':
            plt.figure(figsize=self.fig_size)
            plt.title('Learning curve')
            plt.plot(range(self.max_iter), costs)
            plt.xlabel('Iterations')
            plt.ylabel('Cost')
            if self.save_figs:
                plt.savefig('Learning curve' + '.png')
        if figure_type == 'r':
            to_display = frames[frames['Accuracy'] == 1][
                ['Images', 'Predictions']
            ].head(sample_size)
            images = np.array(list(to_display['Images']))
            predictions = np.array(list(to_display['Predictions']))
            title = f'Classification of {self.target_label} results sample'
            self.display_sample_images(title, images, predictions)
        if figure_type == 'e':
            to_display = frames[frames['Accuracy'] == 0][
                ['Images', 'Predictions']
            ].head(sample_size)
            images = np.array(list(to_display['Images']))
            predictions = np.array(list(to_display['Predictions']))
            title = f'Sample of the misclassified images'
            self.display_sample_images(title, images, predictions)

    def save_run_details(
        self, path, alg, accuracy, total_time, image_size, x_train, x_test, frames
    ):
        """
        Save run details to a .txt file.
        Args:
            path: Path to save the .txt file.
            alg: Classification algorithm.
            accuracy: Train and test accuracy.
            total_time: Total time taken in seconds.
            image_size: Image dimensions.
            x_train: Training set.
            x_test: Test set.
            frames: pandas DataFrame with
        Return:
            None
        """

        with open(path + '/' + 'run_details.txt', 'w') as details:
            details.write(f'Algorithm: {alg}\n')
            details.write(f'Iterations: {self.max_iter} iterations.\n')
            details.write(f'Training accuracy: {accuracy[0]}%\n')
            details.write(f'Test accuracy: {accuracy[1]}%\n')
            details.write(f'Image size: {image_size} x {image_size}\n')
            details.write(f'Learning rate: {self.learning_rate}\n')
            details.write(f'Test sample: {self.test_size}\n')
            details.write(f'Layer dimensions: {self.flat_dimensions}\n')
            details.write(f'Data set size: {len(x_train) + len(x_test)}\n')
            details.write(f'Training set size: {len(x_train)}\n')
            details.write(f'Test set size: {len(x_test)}\n')
            details.write(
                f'Number of {self.target_label} examples: {len(frames[frames["Classification"] == 1])}\n'
            )
            details.write(
                f'Number of non-{self.target_label} examples: {len(frames[frames["Classification"] == 0])}\n'
            )
            details.write(f'Total time: {total_time} seconds.')

    def predict_folder(self, alg, sub_folders=None):
        """
        Classify target label among specified folders.
        Args:
            alg: Algorithm to use for classification:
                'lr': Logistic regression.
                'nn': Neural network.
            sub_folders: Sub_folders to load and process.
        Return:
            pandas DataFrame with the results.
        """
        start_time = perf_counter()
        if self.new_hdf:
            self.clear_hdf(sub_folders)
            self.folders_to_hdf(sub_folders)
        x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, frames = self.pre_process(sub_folders)
        train_predictions, test_predictions, all_predictions, costs = (
            None,
            None,
            None,
            None,
        )
        if alg == 'lr':
            w, b = np.zeros((len(x_train), 1)), 0
            w, b, dw, db, costs = self.g_descent(w, b, x_train, y_train)
            train_predictions = self.predict(w, b, x_train)
            test_predictions = self.predict(w, b, x_test)
            all_predictions = np.append(train_predictions, test_predictions)
        if alg == 'nn':
            initial_parameters = self.initialize_parameters()
            parameters, costs = self.g_descent_nn(x_train, y_train, initial_parameters)
            train_predictions = self.predict_nn(x_train, parameters)
            test_predictions = self.predict_nn(x_test, parameters)
            all_predictions = np.append(train_predictions, test_predictions)
        training_accuracy = 100 - np.mean(np.abs(train_predictions - y_train)) * 100
        test_accuracy = 100 - np.mean(np.abs(test_predictions - y_test)) * 100
        frames['Predictions'] = all_predictions
        frames['Accuracy'] = 0
        frames.loc[frames['Predictions'] == frames['Classification'], 'Accuracy'] = 1
        self.display_message(f'Training accuracy: {training_accuracy}%')
        self.display_message(f'Test accuracy: {test_accuracy}%')
        self.display_message(f'Train predictions: \n{train_predictions}')
        self.display_message(f'Train actual: \n{y_train}')
        self.display_message(f'Test predictions: \n{test_predictions}')
        self.display_message(f'Test actual: \n{y_test}')
        if self.display_figs and 'lc' in self.display_figs:
            self.plot_figure('lc', costs=costs)
        if self.display_figs and 'r' in self.display_figs:
            self.plot_figure('r', frames)
        if self.display_figs and 'e' in self.display_figs:
            self.plot_figure('e', frames)
        if self.show_figs:
            plt.show()
        end_time = perf_counter()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        self.display_message(f'Time: {total_time} seconds.')
        if self.log_file or self.save_figs:
            new_folder_name = f'{alg}-{self.max_iter}-{self.learning_rate}-{random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 7)}'
            os.mkdir(new_folder_name)
            img_size = np.sqrt(self.flat_dimensions[0] / 3)
            self.save_run_details(
                './' + new_folder_name,
                alg,
                (training_accuracy, test_accuracy),
                total_time,
                img_size,
                x_train,
                x_test,
                frames
            )
            for file_name in os.listdir('.'):
                if file_name.endswith('.png') or file_name.endswith('.txt'):
                    shutil.move(file_name, new_folder_name)
        return frames


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clf = ImageClassifier(
        'test_photos/',
        'Dog',
        display_figs=['i', 'lc', 'r', 'e'],
        max_iter=7000,
        learning_rate=0.0015,
        show_figs=True,
        save_figs=True,
        log_file='log.txt',
        random_seed=151
    )
    clf.predict_folder('nn')
```